# Design pattern for a more modular and unittest-able code

Tags: python, pytest

I am refactoring a 700+ line spaghetti function. I see why someone would write it as one big script but using inner functions, I've managed to break it down to more readable & understandable logic.

```py
def cook_all_the_things(a, b):
  c = 'garlic'
  d = None
  e = 'onion'
  f = None
  broken_dishes = False
  burnt_food = False
  
  def _pull_dishes_out():
  def _cook_a():
  def _prep_b():
  def _heat_up_rest():
  def _taste_b_to_z():
  def _cook_others():
  def _clean_up():


  _pull_dishes_out()
  if broken_dishes:
    return
  
  _cook_a()
  if a.tastes_great:
    return a

  ...
```

Each of the helper functions may or may not modify some variables and may or may not cause an early return. Using **nonlocal** vars, fits this scenario well imho.

Now I'm happy with the refactor and want to write some unit tests so the next poor soul who wanders upon this doesn't have to feel like they're disarming landmines like I did.
Oh well, I can't. I learned that I **can't mock and isolate inner functions and write unit tests** for them as they don't exist before the function creation.

One approach I tried was to take the inner functions out but then can't use the nonlocal variables and have to return non-constant number of variables which doesn't really fit this logic well and would introduce the need for additional flags to figure out what was returned.

```py
def _cook_a(a, b):
  if no_dishes:
    return
  if a.tastes_great:
    return a
  return a, b

def cook_all_the_things():
  <call cook_a>
```

Another approach would be to define a dictionary or class instance and pass that object around and keep modifying it in different functions.

All these helper functions only make sense in the context of the big parent function.

Is there a better approach I should be looking into?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As Uncle Bob would say: there is a class hidden in that function. Make the inner functions methods, and the local variables instance variables, and test the class.

Comment: Yes :) though the amount of self I had to sprinkle around made it unappealing. What I ended up doing was to take helpers out, define vars as globals, and dedicate the module to this function. This or class address my need though.